# Isomorphic Flux - get data on server for components

Tags: node.js, reactjs, reactjs-flux, isomorphic-javascript, flummox

In my recent applications I've been using Flux (with flummox - http://acdlite.github.io/flummox) on server per request to make isomorphic rendering. Generally it looked as follows:

```
app.use(createFluxPerRequest);
app.get('/some-route', (req, res) => {
    api.getData(data => {
       req.flux.getActions('items').receiveItems(data);
       next();
    });
});
app.use((req, res) => {
    ReactRouter.run(routes, req.url, Handler => {
        res.render('base', {
            snapshot: new Buffer(req.flux.serialize(), 'utf-8').toString('base64'),
            appString: React.renderToString(
               React.createElement(Handler, { flux: req.flux })
            )
        });
    });
});
```

As you see I've been receiving data through api services however some React components make requests on client on their own.

They doing this by calling e.g. `flux.getActions('items').getSomeDataAsync` action in container components (in `componentDidMount` lifecycle method).

My question - **is it possible (from your experience) to have some method inside container component that will be called on server to call async actions inside it?**

Answer (score 0):

Check out [react-nexus](https://github.com/elierotenberg/react-nexus)

Even though it still remains a work in progress, I think that would "answer" your question

We want to keep fetching data from within the components, but have this data also possibly rendered server side - that's where "isomorphic" will really mean something to react

Too bad this isomorphic word got hyped before actually solving this issue

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I've been using an isomorphic API that can be called from the server and the client in a big react-based isomorphic SPA.

This library that makes it so you can build your APIs in an isomorphic fashion, and re-use it in the client and server without bloating or breaking the bundle. This is what we're currently using in a big single-page application.

It's called Isomorphine, and you can find it here: https://github.com/d-oliveros/isomorphine.

Disclaimer: I'm the author of this library.